# Uninstall Magento module with a script

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, module, programmatically, delete

How do I uninstall a module completely, with it's files and tables, in Magento 1.7.0.2, with an automated script?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built-in solution for this for standard extensions. At the Pre-Imagine 2015 Hackathon, another developer and I came up with a proof of concept, but never completed it. Magento originally was going to include this feature and even created function stubs for it, but for political reasons they never actually wrote the functionality.

Comment: you mean this one https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageTrashApp ?

Comment: I was actually unaware of that one. Ours was just called [Uninstaller](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Uninstaller).

Comment: anayway I was installing that one but the sql tables and files are not going to be deleted just the entry from core_reource